# PHP - Parallel processing

Tags: php, parallel-processing, exec

I'm working on a web application that needs to send a lot of HTTP requests and update the table, this will block the PHP from executing. So I though I might have to write a separate PHP script and run it via my main application. I tried Exec but still the program waits until the script is executed.

```
exec('php do_job.php');
```

I even tried redirecting the output to a file as PHP.Net suggests:

> Note: If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

```
$result = exec('php do_job.php > output.txt &',$output);
```

But still no success ... Further down the same page I came accross this:

```
$command = 'php do_job.php';
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$shell->run($command, 0, false);
```

Still no sucess ... Lastly I tried:

```
pclose(popen("start /B ". $command, "r"));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm developing my app on localhost (XAMPP - Windows), later I'll be releasing it on a Linux host. My last resort would be to run the script via CRON jobs. Is this the only way?

Comment: 1. "send a lot of HTTP requests and update the table" <- elaborate. 2. http://pivotallabs.com/preemptive-optimization/

Comment: 3. Use InnoDB,it has row-level locking instead of myISAM's table-level garbage.

Comment: "send a lot of HTTP requests and update the table" -> I have a bunch of user IDs, I need to call an API for every ID to obtain the information and then update my table. Those API calls will take time, not the saving ...

Answer (score 2):

By just adding `&` at the end of command you can run any command in background. Here I'm redirecting o/p to /dev/null to avoid hang(For Linux).

```
exec('php do_job.php > /dev/null &');
```

If you want see the o/p of the command you can redirect it to a file.

```
exec('php do_job.php > full_path_to_file &');
```

Comment: Except OP is on Windows.

Comment: I don't suppose this works on Windows: exec('php do_job.php > output.txt &');

Comment: Do I need to enable any particular PHP extension?

Comment: No..Also `exec` function will be enabled by default in XAMPP/WAMP

Comment: It's amazing ... I'm running the same code as above but the script hangs until the exec is done ...

Comment: Did u try this ? `exec('php do_job.php > full_path_to_file &');`